# My virtual server is created but it's not showing anything when I visit the site?

Tags: traffic, tracking, virtualhost, webmin

I have created a virtual sever as below for my site:
[image]

I've specified the folder and domain name:

[image]

And I created a master zone for the domain, and NS1 and NS2 has been set for the domain. everything seems good, but when I visit the domain I see the below page without some test files that I've put in the root(www directory):

[image]

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/home/example.com/www"
ServerName example.com
<Directory "/home/example.com/www">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'm doing' wrong?

Comment: What kinds of files are you trying to serve? If it is .php files, you need to have PHP installed. What server software are you using?

Comment: PHP has been installed. I use web min @Christopher

Comment: You need to give more symptoms other than 'it's not working.' For example, what code is behind the page you're requesting? Where is the file? Does it give an error? How are you trying to get to it (Local host, DNS, etc)?

Comment: As you see in the above pic: I have Index of and then cgi-bin directory no file is listed to run it! did you read the whole part of the question? I already said that it is in www directory and www directory is inside mydomain.com directory

Comment: DocumentRoot should be /home/user/, not the www. The domain should route to the www.

Comment: I'm familiar with setting up virtual hosts in a terminal using a2ensite. Have you tried `<VirtualHost *:80>` and also remove any un needed options in the config file. Try with only your doc root, server name, and alias. Then check your main apache2 config file see what it's doc root is place a test file in there and see if it's reading that one. If so maybe your vhost file isn't being read.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It was all OK, but the problem was that Bind server hadn't been started. I couldn't gain any success in webmin so I switched to Kloxo and now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your real apache conf snippet (with example.com instead of your real domain name)?  If so, change the example.com into the other domain name, restart apache and you should be set to go.

Comment: domain name is masked, my domain has been set here.